# Binary search algorithm in Clojure

Tags: beginner, algorithm, functional-programming, clojure, binary-search

I'm absolutely new to Clojure (started learning it yesterday). After I went through some tutorials and checked out the basics I implemented the following Binary search algorithm:

```
(defn log-search
    [elements, elem-to-find]
        (loop [left 0
            right (- (count elements) 1)]
          (when (<= left right)
          (def m (int (Math/floor (/ (+ left right) 2))))
          (def actual (nth elements m))
              (cond
                  (= actual elem-to-find) m
                  (< actual elem-to-find) (recur (+ m 1) right)
                  (> actual elem-to-find) (recur left (- m 1))))))
```

The followings are intentional in the implementation:

1. returning nil on empty sequence
2. I return nil if the element is not present
3. I do not care if `(+ left right)` overflows on very big sequence (I'm focusing only on the language features)

My questions:

1. Is there any Clojure (or funcional programming) antipattern in the
   code?
2. What would be a more functional (or Clojure) approach?

Any other suggestions are more than welcomed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is pretty similar to this one: https://programming-pages.com/2012/01/31/binary-search-in-clojure/

I think the overall algorithm is OK.
You should avoid using `def` inside function - that should be used only for global top-level vars -> use `let` instead.
Also, the code formatting is incorrect - use 2 spaces and proper indentation:

```
(defn log-search
  [elements elem-to-find]
  (loop [left 0
         right (dec (count elements))]
    (when (<= left right)
      (let [m (int (Math/floor (/ (+ left right) 2)))
            actual (nth elements m)]
        (cond
          (= actual elem-to-find) m
          (< actual elem-to-find) (recur (+ m 1) right)
          (> actual elem-to-find) (recur left (- m 1)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `let` rather than `def` inside your `defn`. loop-recur, `reduce` and `iterate` can be substituted for each other. `iterate` is lazy and uses a state->state function that is easy to reason about as you are only looking at the essential thing being done. The tricky part of `iterate` is that it returns an infinite sequence, so you need to know how to stop it. I would recommend starting off with say `(take 3)`, just to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify [Juraj Martinka's solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179701/43360) in several ways:

- Assume that `elements` is a vector. You can make it one using `vec`
  if need be.  This gives us constant time lookup, whereas `nth` is
  linear in the size of `elements`.
- Replace `(int (Math/floor (/ (+ left right) 2)))` with `(quot (+ left
  right) 2)`.
- Drop the final `cond` condition: if reached, it is always true. The
  idiom is to use `:else` as the true value.
- Use `inc` and `dec` where appropriate.

The only significant change is the first.

This gives us

```
(defn log-search
  [elements, elem-to-find]
    (loop [left 0
           right (dec (count elements))]
      (when (<= left right)
        (let [m (quot (+ left right) 2)
              actual (elements m)]
            (cond
              (= actual elem-to-find) m
              (< actual elem-to-find) (recur (inc m) right)
              :else (recur left (dec m)))))))
```

For example,

```
(def stuff [3 5 6])
(map (partial log-search stuff) (range 10))
=> (nil nil nil 0 nil 1 2 nil nil nil)
```